# two managedObjectContext with one managedObject

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsundomanager

I have two entities A and B. A has an to-many relationships to B. A and B have different managedObjectContext contextA and contextB. I need to add managed object B to managed object A after modifying some attributes of B in contextB, but it is impossible because they are not in the same context. So how could i pass changes in contextB to contextA without save it to persistentStore? ps. if u wanna know why i need two different context u could run over this link [undo all changes made in a view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400310/undo-all-changes-made-in-a-view-controller/10405311#comment13445803_10405311).

Answer (score -1):

Copy a managed object from one context to another, you can use the object’s object ID, as illustrated in the following example.

```
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [managedObject objectID];

NSManagedObject *copy = [contextB objectWithID:objectID];
```

After copying you can add the object B to object A.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Actually there is already a object with the same objectID in context2. So [context2 objectWithID:objectID] won't work. Unless i delete the object in context2 first.

Comment: No need to delete the object you can replace the old object with the copied object.

Comment: It doesn't work, as there is already an object B in context A. It could not update the object B in context A with the object B in context B.